# Latex printing text

Tags: positioning

[image]

I tried the above code so as to print as it is typed but i need normal font instead of typewriter font.can anyone guide me

Comment: Can you provide us with your current setup; that is, how are you currently setting the statements in your document? Please create what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: I have edited the post .I want as it is now

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please read the link Werner provided. That is ***not*** an MWE. It is not even a fragment of code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a tabular. This reproduces exactly your image

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ = }ll}
  E & electric field             & [V/m]\\
  s & integration path           & [m]\\
  V & potential in a point       & [V]\\
  U & voltage between electrodes & [V]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway I would use `siunitx` package and do it like that (remember that square brackets usually denote physical dimensions):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}c<{$}@{ = }ls[per-mode=symbol]}
  E & electric field             & \volt\per\meter \\
  s & integration path           & \meter \\
  V & potential in a point       & \volt \\
  U & voltage between electrodes & \volt
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @prabin You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as closed. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)